# Ubuntu is taking more time to boot after reinstalling debian

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I had installed debian on my laptop and now I have triple booted laptop with win7,ubuntu16.04,debian 9(which have bugs).

Now Ubutnu is taking more time to boot up.

I think that it is booting two times(I am noob).

Here is the output of the command `systemd-analyze blame`

```
15.048s dev-sda2.device
     10.180s keyboard-setup.service
      9.765s systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
      8.491s systemd-sysctl.service
      6.719s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
      4.220s grub-common.service
      3.500s upower.service
      2.981s ModemManager.service
      2.427s systemd-udev-trigger.service
      1.752s systemd-logind.service
      1.718s speech-dispatcher.service
      1.712s alsa-restore.service
      1.697s thermald.service
      1.596s systemd-modules-load.service
      1.470s NetworkManager.service
      1.293s accounts-daemon.service
      1.221s systemd-journald.service
      1.163s avahi-daemon.service
      1.155s polkitd.service
      1.044s resolvconf.service
      1.008s lightdm.service
       771ms ufw.service
       697ms systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-b9c06585\x2d9538\x2d46f4\x2d9a
 lines 1-23...skipping...
     15.048s dev-sda2.device
     10.180s keyboard-setup.service
      9.765s systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
      8.491s systemd-sysctl.service
      6.719s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
      4.220s grub-common.service
      3.500s upower.service
      2.981s ModemManager.service
      2.427s systemd-udev-trigger.service
      1.752s systemd-logind.service
      1.718s speech-dispatcher.service
      1.712s alsa-restore.service
      1.697s thermald.service
      1.596s systemd-modules-load.service
      1.470s NetworkManager.service
      1.293s accounts-daemon.service
      1.221s systemd-journald.service
      1.163s avahi-daemon.service
      1.155s polkitd.service
      1.044s resolvconf.service
      1.008s lightdm.service
      771ms ufw.service
      697ms systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-b9c06585\x2d9538\x2d46f4\x2d9af5\x2d96a5e822437f.service
       393ms vboxdrv.service
       387ms kmod-static-nodes.service
       364ms irqbalance.service
       294ms udisks2.service
       293ms gpu-manager.service
       255ms console-setup.service
       243ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
       230ms rsyslog.service
       196ms dev-mqueue.mount
       195ms dev-hugepages.mount
       187ms networking.service
       179ms systemd-rfkill.service
       158ms systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service
    lines 1-36
```

How would you suggest proceeding?